# Extracting Multiple 7z Files Overrides Same Folder

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm currently working on a project where I take multiple 7z files and extract the contents of these files in a folder named the same way as the 7z file itself. I also apologize if something like this has been answered already; I spent time trying to investigate this issue but I can't seem to find anyone else who has had a similar issue.

For example:
a1.7z -> `<targetpath>/a1/<contents within a1.7z>`

The following shell line: `a1.7z | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-o<targetpath>\a1" -y -r}`

Works like a dream, but only for one 7z file. However, whenever I start extracting a second 7z file, it won't create a new folder but instead will continue to add into the same first folder that is created; second folder is never made. When I manually highlight all of the 7z files I want to extract, right click and select "Extract to "*\", it does what I would like it to do but I can't figure out how to script this action. I should also mention that some of the 7z files, when extracted, can contain subfolders of the same name. I'm not sure if this is throwing off the recursion cycle, but I'm assuming this might be the case.

Any help or advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: change `"-o<targetpath>\a1"` to `"-o<targetpath>\$($_.BaseName)"`

Comment: Thank you so much, Mathias! I don't know too much about $_.BaseName but that seems to be where the issue lies; something I'll have to review and understand.

Comment: Just like you use `$_.FullName` to refer to the files path, `$_.BaseName` will expand to the files name minus the extension (so `a1.7z` becomes `a1`, `b2.7z` would be `b2` and so on)

Answer (score 0):

If you get all the .7z files as IOFileInfo objects (Using get-ChildItem) you can use Mathias comment, as one way to do this with the pipeline, but I recommend you put this inside a loop and look for a better way to choose the names of the folders I.e. "NofFolder_$_.BaseName" just in case of more than 1 folder with the same name.

It really depends on the format you want.

Comment: It already is inside a loop. The comment is supposed to correct that code. Also `"NofFolder_$_.BaseName"` would not expand the way you think it would.